# How to add a new record by using Interface in Angular 2?

Tags: angular, data-binding, angular2-forms

I am trying to write the simple CRUD application with Angular 2 and confused about adding a new record.

In most Ng2 tutorials, they are using Interface to represent the objects/records.  So I declared my todo item as the following

```
export interface Itodo {
    todoId: number;    
    description: string;
}
```

and used in my add component and initialize as the following

todo-add.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

import { Itodo } from './todo'

@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    templateUrl: "todo-add.component.html"
})
export class TodoAddComponent {
    //todoModel: Itodo = { todoId : 5, description : "abc" }; <-- it works
    //todoModel: todo; // for class component 
    todoModel: Itodo;

    AddItem(): void {
        console.log('in AddItem');
        console.log(this.todoModel.description);
    }
}
```

my Html

```
<div class="form-horizontal col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class='col-md-3'>Description:</label>
                <div class='col-md-6'><input type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="todoModel.description"></div>
            </div>

            <div class='form-group'>
                <div class='col-md-offset-3 col-md-9'><input type="button" class="btn btn-default" (click)="AddItem()" value="Add Todo Item" /></div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

But I am getting the following Error in the browser

```
core.umd.js:3478 Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Error in http://localhost:57999/app/todo/todo-add.component.html:9:78 caused by: Cannot read property 'description' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'description' of undefined
```

If I changed Interface to Class, everything fines.  Or if I initialize the Interface with the mock class like

```
todoModel: Itodo = { todoId : 5, description : "abc" }
```

It works too.  But I would like to know how I can use the Interface like the other tutorials and how to instatiate with the Interface.

In some stackoverflow posts, they are suggesting to use *ngIf to detect whether it is undefined or not... but I don't know how to use *ngIf and [(ngModel)] together to do the 3 ways binding.

And I don't want to combine create/edit in the same component / html file.  I want to separate them in different files and routings

- todo/add
- todo/edit/5

Could you guys enlighten me how to use the interface properly in ng2?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you figured out yourself, you need to instantiate the object. This is one way to instantiate it, to give it a value like you have:

```
todoModel: Itodo = { todoId : 5, description : "abc" }
```

But you can instantiate an empty object too:

```
todoModel: Itodo = {todoId: null, description: '' }
```

the undefined error you are getting, is because you have not instantiated your object.

If you would use `*ngIf="todoModel"` in your view, that wouldn't really help if you have not instantiated your object, because that would mean that your input field wouldn't show at all, as the `todoModel` is undefined.

Comment: Then does it mean that I cannot use Interface for Create / Insert activities?  the way I am instantiating is wrong and there shouldn't be a data  for the creation on the Init?

Comment: Not sure what you really mean... if you have instantiated your object as an empty object of type `Itodo`, you are in fact using the interface.

Comment: ...Perhaps you viewed my first answer, before I updated it?? I had an error myself and updated the instantiation of the object to a type of `Itodo` (had forgotten the attributes)  Sorry about that ;)

Comment: I wonder why they didn't show this kind of instantiation in any tutotrials.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: No problem! Weird if not in tutorials, this is though pretty essential info... And as a sidenote, about the *ngIf (or safe navigation operator), that is useful when incoming data is async, usually when making http-calls. Then you get to use the ngif or safe navigation operator like crazy all the time :P

Comment: Yeah, even ng2 tutorial - Heroes App is not doing that.  They use #tag and post the string only rather than using 2 ways databinding.....
 <input #heroName />
  <button (click)="add(heroName.value); heroName.value=''">